# Solr get hangs while retriving multiple records via URL

Tags: xml, solr

When i get records from execute query in SOLR admin panel for 10000 Rows.its working fine.

but when i try to get records from following URL my system was hangs appx 30 min.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&rows=10000&wt=xml
```

And i want to parse 100,000 products record using solr.please give any idea about easily parsing 100,000 products record. because only its hangs for appx 10,000 records so how it will work for large number of records.

please give me advice,

thanks
jatin

Comment: What is your system spending time doing? Swapping? CPU? Does it happen with another response writer? (json)

Comment: @MatsLindh i am updated my question and when my system hangs so how to check spending cpu time?

Comment: Using `top` is a good way, depending on which OS you're on. If it's CPU bound, your parsing of the returned XML might be the issue. Doing either a SAX parser or using JSON might be preferred instead.